# How can I base a style on a Silverlight toolkit theme?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, themes, silverlight-toolkit

is it possible to do this?

In my xaml code, I have some ComboBoxes with a style, defined like this:

```
<Style x:Key="comboProjectsStyle"
       TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                               FontSize="14" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="comboDataSourcesStyle"
       TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DescriptiveName}"
                               FontSize="14" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<ComboBox Width="300"
          Style="{StaticResource comboProjectsStyle}" />
<ComboBox Width="300"
          Style="{StaticResource comboDataSourcesStyle}" />
```

The silverlight theme (eg: ExpressionDark) is correctly applied on every controls except on the ones where I have defined a style, like above.

As I understand, in WPF we could use x:Style an base our Style on the silverlight theme using the "BasedOn" property. However, it seems like it is not possible to do so with Silverlight 4.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your ItemTemplate as a resource rather than in a style then your theme style will apply.

```
<UserControl xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    x:Class="Silverlight_Spike.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="14" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <ComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}" />

</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, some of the Style can be reused by other controls, hence why I did not declare them inline :(

Comment: You can define the DataTemplate as a reusable, resource, see my edit.

Comment: How can you apply this to objects that are not in the item control such as control template?For example I want to remove the style of a button, how will I be able to use a Template for that button?

Comment: Define your template at a higher level.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the key in the style:

```
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="14" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
        </Style>
    <Style x:Key="comboProjectsStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="14" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="comboDataSourcesStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DescriptiveName}" FontSize="14" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ComboBox Width="300" Style="{StaticResource comboProjectsStyle}" />
    <ComboBox Width="300" Style="{StaticResource comboDataSourcesStyle}" />

<ComboBox Width="300" />
<ComboBox Width="300" />
<ComboBox Width="300" />
```

Basically this means the style you made above applies to a target type of ComboBox, it is not named therefore every Combobox without a style set to it will inherit this as default.

**UPDATE:**
As you can see all the 3 styles can coexist in the same resource, whenever you use a named style it will be applied to the said control but, for the last three comboboxes, all 3 will be having the style without the key. This is how it is done in themming, like in the JetPack skin from MS.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the fast anwser! Unfortunately I have more than one ComboBox and some of them must use different ComboBox style. So it is not possible for me to remove the x:Key attribute.

Comment: Uhm yes actually let me explain more, you can use the answer i said with conjuction with you named styles :D I'll modify my answer above

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, my problem is that the ExpressionDark Silverlight theme is not applied on my ComboBoxes that have a Style="{ ... }" set. I'm looking for a way to work around this problem :/

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry i misunderstood your question. But I don't think thats possible in SL :)

Comment: What I did is that I've copied the xaml resource of the theme and added it to my project then I added a key for each of the controls. Now every time I am using a control with a specific style i use i.e. BasedOn={StaticResource ThemeButton}.

With this solution you'll be using the original theme and a modified one for your based on. So all your unstyled controls will follow the original theme and all your styled controls will be based on the copied theme with keys.

I know this is not the best solution, but it's better than nothing. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is not exactly using basedOn but by using a converter we can achieve the goal of basing the custom style to the theme. Here's how we do it.

1. Expose a Theme and place it where you can bind it to the style.
2. Create a value converter to convert the style that you are using. This converter will return a style that is based on the theme, so here's a snippet.

   ```
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
       if (parameter is Style)
       {
           Style retStyle = parameter as Style;
           Theme themeContainer;
           if (value is Theme)
               themeContainer = value as Theme; //(App.Current as App).AppTheme;
           else
               themeContainer = (App.Current as App).AppTheme; 

           if (themeContainer != null)
           {
               foreach (DictionaryEntry i in themeContainer.ThemeResources)
               {
                   if (i.Value is Style)
                   {
                       Style t = i.Value as Style;
                       if (t.TargetType == retStyle.TargetType)
                       {
                           Style newStyle = new Style();
                           newStyle.TargetType = retStyle.TargetType;
                           newStyle.BasedOn = t;

                           foreach (Setter set in retStyle.Setters)
                               newStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter() { Property = set.Property, Value = set.Value }); 

                           return newStyle;                                              
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
           return retStyle;
       }
       return null; 
   }
   ```
3. Bind the theme to the style and use the converter on every custom style that you use

   Style="{Binding Theme, Converter={StaticResource styleConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource ButtonStyle1}}"

Where theme is a property of type Theme(System.Windows.Controls.Theming).

I uplaoded my sample project [here](http://fileape.com/dl/NZLUiXutSSXRs5oS)
The sample code is not updated but you can start from there.